# AWS CLI query and filter for Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-step-functions

I would like to get Step Function ARN using AWS CLI by name with wildcard strig or get Step Function ARN by Step Function name

Here is an example:

```
    aws stepfunctions list-state-machines --region us-east-1
```

I got this:

```
{
    "stateMachines": [
        {
            "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:012345678912:stateMachine:firstStepFunc",
            "name": "firstStepFunc",
            "type": "STANDARD",
            "creationDate": "2022-12-01T14:43:09.577000+01:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried this one:

```
    aws stepfunctions list-state-machines --query 'stateMachines[*].stateMachineArn' --region us-east-1 --output text
```

And get expected result:

```
    arn:aws:states:us-east-1:012345678912:stateMachine:firstStepFunc
```

But if Step Functions will be more than one, it won't work.

I need something like that, but I have no idea how to write query in proper way:

```
    aws stepfunctions list-state-machines --query 'stateMachines[*].stateMachineArn[?stateMachineArn==`*`]' --region us-east-1
```

```
    aws stepfunctions list-state-machines --query 'stateMachines[*].stateMachineArn[?name==`*`]' --region us-east-1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `aws stepfunctions list-state-machines --query 'stateMachines[*].stateMachineArn[?name=='*first*']' --region us-east-1`
and expected result:
`arn:aws:states:us-east-1:012345678912:stateMachine:firstStepFunc`

Comment: Yes, but I want to get ARN by name or part of the name, for example, all step functions with "dev" word in name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`contains`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains) functions for this, for example:

```
aws stepfunctions list-state-machines --query 'stateMachines[?contains(name,`dev`)]|[*].stateMachineArn' --region us-east-1 --output text
```

The expression above returns the ARN of all stepfunctions which have the `dev` keyword in their name. If you want to get only one (the first one, for example), you can do the following:

```
aws stepfunctions list-state-machines --query 'stateMachines[?contains(name,`dev`)]|[0].stateMachineArn' --region us-east-1 --output text
```

Comment: It works great! Thank you!
Do you know, is it possible to use wildcards?
For example:
`aws stepfunctions list-state-machines --query 'stateMachines[?contains(name,\`data*dev\`)]|[*].stateMachineArn' --region us-east-1 --output text`

Comment: Figured it out with several **contains** in expression:
`stateMachines[?contains(name,\`tep\`) && contains(name,\`first\`)]|[*].stateMachineArn`